# How to change window position in X11 Viewer

Tags: ubuntu, position, window, x11, jdownloader

my VNC Viewer shows only half of the screen :/

I'm using JDownloader in combination with my.jdownloader as a deamon on my ubuntu 14.04 server for my personal downloads.

In my.jdownloader are many different settings possible. But I'd like to have the original gui, if i wanne change something special. I was going to use x11vnc. I installed and configured it, but when I'm successfully connecting to the VNC session, I only got half the GUI window.

Not that the VNC window isn't wide enought. NO! The window is just beginning at the middle of the VNC window, so the rest is moving out of the vnc screen.

Here are all configurations I use at the moment:

```
JDSTART  ="DISPLAY=:1 java -jar $JD2DIR/JDownloader.jar"
XVFBSTART="Xvfb :1"
X11START ="x11vnc -display :1 -xkb"
```

I can not grab and move the window and I don't know how to configure the window position. Can anyone help at that?

Here a screeny of my VNC Viewer window.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdotool, in terminal

1. export DISPLAY=:1
2. xdotool search --any "JDow"
3. xdotool windowmove xxxxx 0 0 ( xxxx number from step 2 )

I'm looking something better than this, but, it is working

EDIT

You have to install  window manager, for example blackbox, fluxbox, or flwm.
Next add to your script this:
blackbox -display :1

Found https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=64399